# Android Studio with custom framework - spurious unresolved reference warning: how to suppress it?

Tags: android, ide

I have a custom frameworks.jar, which is compiled from AOSP by myself, to invoke the hidden method, nameSurfaceControl.screenshot(). I know that this is not a good way to take a screenshot, but just for tests. Anyway, although it compiles well and runs ok on AVD, IDE complains to me that screenshot() is an unresolved reference:

[unresolved reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltp18.png)

my gradle.build (for module)

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'myframeworks.jar'
}
```

Is there any way to fix it or suppress it?